# Can't upgrade due to 404 error

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

The upgrade is successfully started, but then  got this error:

```
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/dapper/main/source/Sources 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
...
```

The Internet connection is fine. When I simply open that URL in browsed I still get 404.

/etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric main restricted
deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric main restricted

deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates main restricted

deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric universe
deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric universe
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates universe
deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates universe

deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric multiverse
deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric multiverse
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates multiverse
deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security multiverse

deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric main
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu dapper main multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu dapper-updates main multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner
```

How can I get through this?

Comment: @JacobJohanEdwards here's the /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: no, we have mixed sources, and two of them EOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason you trying to download Ubuntu 6.06 aka Dapper Drake which is of course not supported for some time. You should check your Software Sources or check file /etc/apt/sources.list.

Looking at your file:

```
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu dapper main multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu dapper-updates main multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner
```

These lines need to be commented out:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

add a `#` in-front of the lines above i.e.

```
#deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu dapper main multiverse
#deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu dapper-updates main multiverse
#deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner
#deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner
```

Save.

Run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Reboot

Then perform the upgrade as per:

[How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-from-10-04-or-11-10-to-12-04)

Answer (score 0):

as stated above the Ubuntu server failed due to some other reasons.
You can either wait for the issue to be fixed or you can simply download the Ubuntu 12.04 iso boot it up and click "Update Ubuntu" in the Ubuntu installer.

Maybe you can upgrade your system this way.

I hope this was helpful. :)